# A sql query that executes without any errors on mysql client fails with a syntax error when executed through code

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-5.6

I need to add a partition to an already partitioned table. My code adds a partition p190409 that would hold some data. The query is as follows:

```
alter table db.table drop partition future;
alter table db.table add partition (partition p190409 values less than (to_days('2019-04-09 11:50:06')));
alter table db.table add partition (partition future values less than (MAXVALUE));
```

The same while working perfectly fine on a mysql client, yields the following error through code:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'alter table db.table add partition (partition p190409 values
>   less' at line 1

Comment: why are you try to do this in Java?

Comment: I've to write an API that would be scheduled to run everyday, to add a partition corresponding to that day

Comment: Many MySQL API's cannot execute more than one query in a call. Try splitting it into three queries.

Comment: @Nick, Makes sense, will try it out and update info here

Comment: @Nick, Thanks, your suggestion fixed the issue

Comment: @cricketeer it seems I should have posted it as an answer! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the method you are using to execute the query only admit one at the time, so instead off executing all queries at once do it one by one:

```
executeUpdate("alter table db.table drop partition future");
executeUpdate("alter table db.table add partition (partition p190409 values less than (to_days('2019-04-09 11:50:06')))");
executeUpdate("table db.table add partition (partition future values less than (MAXVALUE))");
```

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks for your observations, I have correct them :)